# inequality two measures in a field

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a field of subsets of  $X$ such that $\mathcal{F}$ is the $\sigma$-field generated by $\mathcal{A}$, and let $\mu_1$, $\mu_2$ be two measures which are $\sigma$-finite.

Show that:
if $\mu_1(A)\leq \mu_2(A)$ for every $A\in\mathcal{A}$, then this inequality holds for every element in $\mathcal{F}$.

I think it is related to the Caratheodory Extension Theorem, but I have no idea how to deal with the inequality given. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know about the Monotone class theorem?